# Cannot post a zip file in Python. Unicode decoding error

Tags: python, urllib2

When trying to submit a zip file using urllib2 I am getting a UnicodeDecodeError with the following messages:

```
Exception during urlopen: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
Exception: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
Exception of type: <type 'exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError'>
Exception. Message: "". Doc: "Unicode decoding error.".
Exception during export: 
e.__doc__=Unicode decoding error.
```

The exception is raised on the line `response = urllib2.urlopen(request)`.

```py
    def depositZipFile(tempZipFileName, tempZipFilePath, depositUrl, tr):
        print('depositZipFile(). tempZipFileName=%s, tempZipFilePath=%s, depositUrl=%s, tr=%s' % (tempZipFileName, tempZipFilePath, depositUrl, str(tr)))
        with open(tempZipFilePath, 'rb') as f:
            zipData = f.read()
            print('depositZipFile(). type(zipData)=%s' % type(zipData))

            headers = {
                'In-Progress': 'true',
                'Content-Disposition': 'filename=' + tempZipFileName,
                'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
                'Content-Length': os.stat(tempZipFilePath).st_size,
                'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'binary',
                'Packaging': 'http://purl.org/net/sword/package/METSDSpaceSIP',
            }

            try:
                request = urllib2.Request(depositUrl, data=zipData, headers=headers)

                try:
                    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
                except Exception as e:
                    print('Exception during urlopen: ' + str(e))
                    raise e

                print('Got response. response=%s' % str(response))

                xmlText = response.read()
                xmlRoot = ET.fromstring(xmlText)
                linkElement = xmlRoot.find('xmlns:link[@rel="alternate"]', namespaces=dict(xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'))

                if linkElement is None:
                    raise ValueError('No redirection URL is found in the response.')

                href = linkElement.attrib['href']
                return href
            except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
                print('HTTPError: ' + str(e))
                print('HTTPError: %s' % str(e.code))
                print('HTTPError message: %s' % e.read())
                raise e
            except Exception as e:
                print('Exception: ' + str(e))
                print('Exception of type: %s' % type(e))
                print('Exception. Message: "%s". Doc: "%s".' % (e.message, e.__doc__))
                raise e
```

Before the aforementioned method is called the user is authenticated using basic authentication. See the following method.

```py
    def authenticateUser(tr, url):
        user = getConfigurationProperty(tr, 'user')
        password = getConfigurationProperty(tr, 'password')
        realm = getConfigurationProperty(tr, 'realm')
        pm = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgr()
        pm.add_password(realm, url, user, password)
        authHandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(pm)
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(authHandler)
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

I am very new to Python and maybe I am missing something obvious. Please advise.

I am using Python 2.7, Jython implementation.

Comment: Not sure if it is possible for you. But listen, if you are "very new to Python", use Python3. Python2 is dying.

Comment: @Sraw thank you for the advice, but unfortunately it is not possible for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparently the problem was that the type of `depositUrl` was `unicode` instead of `str`. Therefore, the `urllib2.Request()` method was expecting `unicode` types for all parameters. When I made the following conversion everything srtarted working:

```py
depositUrl = str(depositUrl)
```